# jquery .on function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've updated my jquery script to 1.9.1 and a function stoped working with `.live()`.

I have got `.on()` working but now it doesnt remove the item from the list, I have to update the page to see the result.

generate the html-code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
    {
        $('#listInserts').append('<div>' + o[i].text + '<a class="del" rel="'+ o[i].dataid +'" href="#">X</a></div>');
    }
```

code before

```
$('.del').live('click', function() {
        delItem = $(this);
        var dataid = $(this).attr('rel');

        $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'dataid': dataid}, function(o) {
            delItem.parent().remove();
        }, 'json');

        return false;
    });
```

code after

```
$(document).on('click','.del', function() {
        delItem = $(this);
        var dataid = $(this).attr('rel');

        $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'dataid': dataid}, function(o) {
            delItem.parent().remove();
        }, 'json');

        return false;
    });
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Looks about right on first glance, but not sure why you would declare `delItem` in the global scope? And `this` would normally refer to the `.del` element clicked, not the `document` !

Comment: @Rob - That is incorrect.  `$(this)` will refer to the element clicked, not `document`.

Comment: @Steve - `e.target` would be the element clicked, `this` would be the element bound, in this case `.del`. Often times they are the same.

Comment: @adeneo - Absolutely correct.  I mixed up terminology. As you stated `e.target` is the click origination, while `$(this)` is the element the click is bound to.

Comment: @simmern could you show your HTML markup? Are you *sure* you didn't change any of your HTML?

Comment: It should be rather simple to debug. Either the element you're trying to remove is'nt there, or the ajax function fails, or the click function never runs!

Comment: Yes, [the documentation for `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) explains `this` for direct and delegated event handling (though not unambiguously). See the last paragraph under "The event handler and its environment".

Comment: this for-loop genertats the html-code:
 'for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++){
   $('#listInserts').append('<div>' + o[i].text + '<a class="del" rel="'+ o[i].dataid +'" href="#">X</a></div>');
}'

and has no changes.

Comment: Can you edit that into the question please @Simmern, properly formatted.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot have edit my question and found a solution for it

Comment: @Simmern Since it seems you found a solution, you could post an answer describing what you did and accept it for others to see this is solved...

Comment: @Simmern, that's not doing the same as the original code. There are two differences; (1) the event is not delegated, so `.del` elements added later will not be handled, and (2) removal happens unconditionally, regardless of whether the ajax is successful or not. Try the code in my answer below.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot with your last comment I got an Idee and tryed.

turned out that I retruned true from my model but waited for `JSON`. and got the problem solved, now inside the post-finction,

Comment: OK but my point (1) still applies. Presumably there was a reason for using `.live()`, so it's dangerous to assume that delegation is now not necessary. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With knowledge of the HTML structure and knowing that 'json' is not appropriate, you might try this :

```
$('#listInserts').on('click','.del', function() {
    var delItem = $(this);
    var dataid = delItem.attr('rel');
    $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'dataid': dataid}, function(o) {
        delItem.closest('div').remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem

```
$('.del').on('click', function() {
    delItem = $(this);
    var dataid = $(this).attr('rel');

    $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'dataid': dataid}, function(o) {
delItem.parent().remove();



    });
            return false;
});
```

turned out that Im returning true from my model but waited for a JSON object. Removed `,JSON`and it worked as it shall.

Comment: Great, now try the code in my answer, which replicates the functionality of the old code. The differences could be significant.

Comment: Simmern, I hope I encouraged you in the right direction. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Yes you did, jQuery is pretty new for me and I start get the grip of it, bin away from programming for too long time. Never going happen agen LoL. Thanks for the help =))